# Java library for testing web services

Tags: java, web-services, junit, integration-testing

I have `JUnit` tests for REST web services. Now I think that `JUnit` is not the best tool for that, since these tests are *integration* tests but not *unit* tests. So I probably need a Java library, which helps to send HTTP requests, verify HTTP responses, create reports and do that in parallel.

On the other hand maybe I am mistaken and `Junit` (with `HTTPUnit` etc.) is good enough and I don't need other tools.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing similar questions... and am starting looking around and experimenting.

I found this is other stackoverflow question: [Unit testing a JAX-RS Web Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121266/unit-testing-a-jax-rs-web-service) (apparently Jersey allows to make such type of tests).

These are two options that popped up:

- https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/
- https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple. Have a look at https://github.com/valid4j/http-matchers

```
// Statically import the library entry point:
import static org.valid4j.matchers.http.HttpResponseMatchers.*;

// Invoke your web service using plain JAX-RS. E.g:
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response response = client.target("http://example.org/hello").request("text/plain").get();

// Verify the response
assertThat(response, hasStatus(Status.OK));
assertThat(response, hasHeader("Content-Encoding", equalTo("gzip")));
assertThat(response, hasEntity(equalTo("content")));
// etc...
```