# why javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder object is not able to create in junit test case

Tags: java, junit

I created an object of `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder` and  pass to the method this is working fine in the project but when i created object in junit test cases then at run time after that creation of object next statement its not executing.

This is my test case code.

```
@Test
public void testGetCountryDetails() {
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok();
    CountryDetails countryDetails=new CountryDetails();
    boolean status=countryDetails.getCountryDetails(builder);
    log.debug("the status is"+status);
    log.debug("the body is:"+builder.build().getEntity());
    assertTrue(status);
}
```

Comment: How are you running the junit test case? Using IDE or ant?

Comment: place your code in a try catch block and in the catch block print the exception trace. And share that exception trace, for us to reach at the RCA for this.

Comment: this is link:http://www.docdroid.net/58dj/error.txt.html

Comment: if i run from maven then i getting
 testGetCountryDetails(com.test.CountryDetailsTest): Absent Code attr
ibute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ws/rs/core/Re
sponse
error

Comment: Seems like you need the container initialized before being able to unit test what ever you are trying to test. See this link about unit testing JAX-RS webservice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121266/unit-testing-a-jax-rs-web-service

Comment: so how can i initialize jax-rs?.

Comment: see the link i have provided in my comment.

Comment: i checked but for that i need to used jersey library?

Comment: i change org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseBuilderImpl then its woking fine. do u tell me why?

Comment: I am not that aware with Jersey but I can tell you the reason that probably the Impl class might not be using the container specific settings but ResponseBuilder.getInstance() method might be using. So due to that it might be working. Again I am not sure, this is just a speculation.