# Jersey stopped working with InjectionManagerFactory not found

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, jersey-2.0

I am receiving below error while running my Jersey API in Tomcat 8.5.11 which is causing my API to stop:

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw
>   exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST
>   Service threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found.
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lookupInjectionManagerFactory(Injections.java:97)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:89)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:335)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The application is build with the following dependencies with gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile (
        // REST
        "org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.+",
        "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.+",
        // REST Token
        "org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.+",
        // MongoDB
        "org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-bom:5.+",
        "org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-infinispan:5.+",
        "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.+",
        "org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.+",
        "org.jboss.narayana.jta:narayana-jta:5.+",
        "org.jboss:jboss-transaction-spi:7.+",
        "log4j:log4j:1.+",
        "org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-mongodb:5.+",
        "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.+"
    ) }
```

This downloads `jersey-common-2.26-b04.jar` which contains the missing class under `/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/InjectionManagerFactory`. The jar file is deployed into the Tomcat folder under `WEB-INF/lib`

What can be wrong here? The gradle script worked the last few month with the same Tomcat version.

Comment: i see there was a new version of jersey on 19/05 - check if this is the problem, i have the same problem currently

Comment: https://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.glassfish.jersey.core%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jersey-common%22

Comment: This tutorial helped me fix this issue http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/

Answer (score 402):

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.28</version>
</dependency>
```

cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44536542/1070215

Make sure not to mix your Jersey dependency versions. This answer says version "2.28", but use whatever version your other Jersey dependency versions are.

Comment: Worked for me with 2.26 release version. Didn't want to use beta versions in production code.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer.
Works with 2.26

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51217530/2587435) for explanation.

Comment: This was it for me - version 2.28.

Comment: What was bizzare for me was that it was working, and then it stopped working UNTIL I did the above inclusion as per this post. Anyhow, thank you. My core version was 2.30 and my inject version as above i.e. 2.28.

Comment: @Beezer No, No, don't mix your Jersey dependency versions. If your jersey-core (which you should not even need, as it's a transitive) is 2.30, then your jersey-hk2 should be 2.30. Mixing versions always leads to weird problems.

Comment: Still works and needed for 3.0.2. Why they didn't fix this in a new major version is beyond me.

Comment: Worked for me with jersey 2.38.

Answer (score 160):

Jersey 2.26 and newer are not backward compatible with older versions. The reason behind that has been stated in the [release notes](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/release-notes/2.26.html):

> Unfortunately, there was a need to make backwards incompatible changes
> in 2.26. Concretely jersey-proprietary reactive client API is
> completely gone and cannot be supported any longer - it conflicts with
> what was introduced in JAX-RS 2.1 (that's the price for Jersey being
> "spec playground..").
>
> Another bigger change in Jersey code is attempt to make Jersey core
> independent of any specific injection framework. As you might now,
> Jersey 2.x is (was!) pretty tightly dependent on HK2, which sometimes
> causes issues (esp. when running on other injection containers. **Jersey
> now defines it's own injection facade**, which, when implemented
> properly, replaces all internal Jersey injection.

---

As for now one should use the following dependencies:

**Maven**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:2.26'
```

Comment: Also see issue [Cannot upgrade from 2.25.1 to 2.26](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3664)

Comment: Sigh... why wouldn't Jersey bump the version to 3.0 if they are making a breaking change..

Comment: @trevorism I have a feeling they want to keep the major version in sync with the JAX-RS major version. That's the only thing that makes sense to me.

Comment: Also jersey-common is not a requirement (to _manually_ add). This should already be pulled in by jersey-server, which should be pulled in by jersey-container-servlet-core or any other "main" jersey dependency you use. The only required dependency to get rid of the error in question is the jersey-hk2 (or jersey-cdi2-se, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51217530/2587435)).

Answer (score 65):

Here is the reason. Starting from Jersey 2.26, Jersey removed HK2 as a ***hard*** dependency. It created an SPI as a facade for the dependency injection provider, in the form of the `InjectionManager` and `InjectionManagerFactory`. So for Jersey to run, we need to have an implementation of the `InjectionManagerFactory`. There are two implementations of this, which are for [HK2 and CDI](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/tree/master/inject). The HK2 dependency is the `jersey-hk2` others are talking about.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

The CDI dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-cdi2-se</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

This (jersey-cdi2-se) should only be used for SE environments and not EE environments.

Jersey made this change to allow others to provide their own dependency injection framework. They don't have any plans to implement any other `InjectionManager`s, though others have made [attempts at implementing one for Guice](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3692).

Comment: Note that using CDI (jersey-cdi2-se) requires a bean.xml configuration in META-INF. Otherwise following exception will be thrown: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-ENV-000016: Missing beans.xml file in META-INF

Comment: This answer helpped me with so many inconsistencies, +1 for clarifying jersey-cdi2-se should only be used for SE

Answer (score 13):

Choose which DI to inject stuff into Jersey:

Spring 4:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-spring4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Spring 3:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

HK2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It's not that easy. You can't just switch out HK2 for Spring. The `jersey-spring` integration still uses a HK2 bridge under the hood to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could solve it was via:

org.glassfish.jersey.core
        jersey-server
        ${jersey-2-version}

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-2-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-2-version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-2-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-2-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

So, only if I added `jersey-container-servlet` and `jersey-hk2` would it run without errors

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see dependencies have changed between 2.26-b03 and 2.26-b04 (HK2 was moved to from compile to testCompile)... there might be some change in the jersey dependencies that has not been completed yet (or which lead to a bug).

However, right now the simple solution is to stick to an older version :-)

Answer (score -3):

Here is the new dependency (August 2017)

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m03</version>
</dependency>
```