# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception REST web-service error

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, jersey

I keep recieving the HTTP Status 500 error while trying to access a resource using Jersey. I already tried a lot of things, reached to the second page of google searches haha and nothing.

Here is my code:

The resource class:

```
@Path("/course")

public class CourseResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getCourse(){
        return "this is a dummy course!";

    }

}
```

web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.paul.licenta.teachApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.paul.licenta</groupId>
    <artifactId>teachApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>teachApp</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>teachApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
           <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26-b06</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

And here is the error that I get:

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found.
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lambda$lookupInjectionManagerFactory$0(Injections.java:98)
    java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lookupInjectionManagerFactory(Injections.java:98)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:93)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.78 logs.
```

[HERE IS THE PROJECT EXPLORER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X8op.png)

ANY IDEAS ON HOW I COULD MAKE THIS WORK?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey stopped working with InjectionManagerFactory not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088493/jersey-stopped-working-with-injectionmanagerfactory-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<jersey.version>2.26-b06</jersey.version>
```

Try downgrading to the version deployed in March 2.26-b03.

Comment: @PaulBuciuman don't forget to accept the answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error, so I decided to play around with the project facets. Found that using setting Project Facet "Java" to "9" worked well.