# Spring boot mock CREATED POST response

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, jax-rs, httpresponse

Completely new to spring-boot.

I am trying to write a test for my POST method that returns a response of CREATED with the path of the resource. I am coming across all sorts of problems for something that I was assuming is very straight forward. In the code bellow is my current test class which seems to be crashing with a

> ClassNotFoundException

on the first line of my method.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AResource.class)
public class AResourceTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private AResource aResourceMock;

    @Test
    public void testPOST() throws Exception {
        Response.ResponseBuilder created = Response.created(UriBuilder.fromPath("/123").build());
        when(aResourceMock.create(123)).thenReturn(created.build());

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .request(HttpMethod.POST, "/account")
                .content("{\t\"id\": \"123\"}"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated());
    }
}
```

Any idea how to properly mock my response? Thanks

EDIT:
stacktrace bellow

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl

    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:122)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:69)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromPath(UriBuilder.java:111)
    at com.powerman.RestController.AResourceTest.canPOST(AResourceTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:62)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:155)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:105)
    ... 34 more
```

I will add my dependencies in case they help at all:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: you need to add spring-test to your maven dependencies, for example:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: i am using sping-boot and I am already importing: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: can you post your stacktrace error ?

Comment: @guilhebl Added stacktrace to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do and why you would want to mock the `Response`. When you are running a a test for your resources, generally wha you want to do is run integration tests. What this entails is making an actual request to the endpoint using a client library. `MockMvc` only works when you are using Spring MVC as the REST framework. But in your case, you are using Jersey (I assume, based on the [jax-rs](/questions/tagged/jax-rs) tag in your post.

As far as the client library, you can use the [Jersey/JAX-RS Client API](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html) or you can use Spring Boot's `TestRestTemplate`, like they do in the [official Spring Boot/Jersey sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey/src/test/java/sample/jersey/SampleJerseyApplicationTests.java). For checking the created URI for the POST/Created resource, what you should be doing is checking the `Location` header in the response. This is was is set on the server side when you do `Response.created(URI)`. For example, say this is your resource

```
@Path("customers")
public class CustomersResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createCustomer(Customer customer, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        int customerId = // create customer and get the resource id
        UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
        builder.path(Integer.toString(customerId));
        return Response.created(builder.build()).build();
    }
}
```

Jersey will automatically set the `Location` to value of the URI passed to `created()`

Then (if you're using the Jersey Client), then your test might look something like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ExampleResourceTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();


    @Test
    public void testCustomerLocationOnPost() {
        Customer customer = new Customer("Jane", "Doe");

        URI resourceUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost")
                .port(port).path("api").path("customers").build();

        Response response = client.target(resourceUri).request().post(Entity.json(customer));

        // test that we get the correct status code
        assertThat(response.getStatus())
                .isEqualTo(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode());

        // test that the location header is correct.
        assertThat(response.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.LOCATION))
                .isEqualTo(UriBuilder.fromUri(resourceUri).path("123").build().toString());
    }
}
```

As far as the dependencies, to use Jersey with Spring Boot you need to use the `spring-boot-started-jersey` dependency. Also get rid of the `jersey-core` dependency you have. See the linked project above for complete example.

Comment: that is causing a `InjectionManagerFactory not found` when doing the post request. Looking into that

Comment: It has to do with the dependenc(ies) version you are using with Jersey. This problem started in 2.26 and to fix it you need to add jersey-hk2 dependency.

Comment: looking into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088493/jersey-stopped-working-with-injectionmanagerfactory-not-found?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa that mentions that. However, I am back to `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder` on the `ClientBuilder.newClient();`.. I don't know why it's so messy. What's the point of spring-boot if not to make that easier :/

Comment: You need to be using `spring-boot-starter-jersey`. And get rid of `jersey-core`. Look at the official example I linked to.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-boot-upload-example) another simple application setup (you just need to add the spring-boot-starter-test to it). And here are the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jersey). It's actually pretty simple. It's only complicated if you don't know what you're doing and reading the wrong learning resources.

Comment: I was following the tutorial from spring.io 
anyway, it seems to have done the job. Thanks. Do you mind adding the comment to your main answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: didn't make a difference