# InjectionManagerFactory not found after jersey version update

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I update jersey to 2.30 and i have error

```
37] [class=resolver.PortletExceptionResolverImpl] [method=resourceRequestException] [InjectionManagerFactory not found.]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lambda$lookupInjectionManagerFactory$0(Injections.java:74)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
```

I add org.glassfish.hk2.external javax.inject and org.glassfish.jersey.inject  jersey-hk2 
but it didn’t help

Comment: Problems with breaking changes after version 2.25. [similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088493/jersey-stopped-working-with-injectionmanagerfactory-not-found)